# When I show a hidden div I can not access the information, it blinks

Tags: jquery, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am working on a table aviso with information from the bd, then a td (title) assign events onmouseover and onmouseout to show me a hidden div, when I pass the mouse for each of the td shows me the information of each notice, but I can not see the information of the div well because it blinks, it does not remain static while I work in it.

try with modal and do the same thing

I have tried with setTimeout but it does not work because it remains the div of another id for a while.

Code td

```
<td id="tdtitle" onmouseover="enable({{ $avisos->id }})" onmouseout="disable({{ $avisos->id }})">{{ $avisos->title}}</td>
```

Code Div

```
<div class="avisoDetail" id="detail{{ $avisos->id }}">
  <a class="btn" href="#" title="">{{ $avisos->id }}</a>
</div>
```

Code JS

```
function enable(e){
  $("#detail"+e).show();
}
function disable(e){
  $("#detail"+e).hide();
}
```

Code CSS

```
.avisoDetail{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #df7401;
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 24%;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    width: 776px;
    z-index: 9999;
    min-height: 800px;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 12px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

We need to access the information inside the div but if I move the mouse it starts blinking

Comment: This works fine in a plain environment so it's not really possible to debug. One suggestion I would make is to try `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` instead.

Answer (score 0):

should be better this way ?

HTML body

```
<td id="tdtitle" data-ref="{{ $avisos->id }}">{{ $avisos->title}}</td>
```

Javascript

```
$("#tdtitle").hover(
    function () {
      let refID = '#detail' + $(this).data('ref');
      $(refID).show();
    },
    function () {
      let refID = '#detail' + $(this).data('ref');
      $(refID).hide();
    }
);
```

and possibly have a message in return to know ?

Comment: It happens the same to me when you open that day and I'll place the mouse inside the information that detail begins to twinkle,  it does not stay fixed

Comment: I think the problem comes from elsewhere, there must be another element that comes to cover the cell and trigger the mouseOut?
but without knowing the exact context, we can not guess anything

Comment: Actually I'm not very expert in this, I just work doing something horrible but it works, adds the function .mousemove () to the detail and in the js to that function I returned to do the show and remains visible to work with information

Comment: Yes, the problem must really come from there